# How can I write a mathematical formula in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to write a formula that does the following :

- takes the `LOS_Day` (calculated datediff with two columns `AdmitDate` and `DischargeDate`) and multiplies it by 100, then divides it by `NumberofBeds` (was calculated using the `Count` function from `V_Bed` table) and multiplies it by input date range (number of days) from the user `@fromdate - @todate`

[image]

Find the query I used here:

```
SELECT 
    pt.regcode, 
    pt.admissionnumber, 
    pt.admissionid, 
    pt.admitdate, 
    pt.dischargedate, 
    wardbed.bedid, 
    bed.bedname, 
    wardbed.ward, 
    DATEDIFF(HOUR, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate) AS LOS_Hour, 
    DATEDIFF(DAY, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate)  AS LOS_day, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM v_beds) AS NumberofBeds 
FROM   
    v_bedallocations bed, 
    v_dbpatientadmissions pt, 
    v_beds wardbed  
WHERE  
    pt.admissionnumber = bed.admissionnumber 
    AND pt.admissionid = wardbed.admissionid 
    AND bed.bedname = wardbed.bedname 
GROUP BY 
    bed.bedname, pt.regcode, pt.admissionnumber, 
    pt.admissionid, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate, 
    wardbed.bedid, bed.bedname, wardbed.ward
```

Here's the output from that query:
[image]

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the famous words of Nike, "Just Do It!" (Just plug the formula right into your `SELECT` line; however, you might consider a scalar function as a cleaner way to do it.)

```
SELECT pt.regcode, 
           pt.admissionnumber, 
           pt.admissionid, 
           pt.admitdate, 
           pt.dischargedate, 
           wardbed.bedid, 
           bed.bedname, 
           wardbed.ward, 
           Datediff(hour, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate) AS LOS_Hour, 
           Datediff(day, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate)  AS LOS_day, 
           (SELECT Count(*) FROM   v_beds) AS NumberofBeds,
           100 * Datediff(day, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate)/(Count(*)*Datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)) as JustDoItInlineFormulaResult
FROM   v_bedallocations bed, 
           v_dbpatientadmissions pt, 
           v_beds wardbed 
WHERE  pt.admissionnumber = bed.admissionnumber 
           AND pt.admissionid = wardbed.admissionid 
           AND bed.bedname = wardbed.bedname 
GROUP  BY bed.bedname, 
              pt.regcode, 
              pt.admissionnumber, 
              pt.admissionid, 
              pt.admitdate, 
              pt.dischargedate, 
              wardbed.bedid, 
              bed.bedname, 
              wardbed.ward
```

This approach should work because it doesn't use non-aggregated fields, but you could always pull out your current query into a CTE, like so:

```
with CTE AS (
SELECT pt.regcode, 
               pt.admissionnumber, 
               pt.admissionid, 
               pt.admitdate, 
               pt.dischargedate, 
               wardbed.bedid, 
               bed.bedname, 
               wardbed.ward, 
               Datediff(hour, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate) AS LOS_Hour, 
               Datediff(day, pt.admitdate, pt.dischargedate)  AS LOS_day, 
               (SELECT Count(*) FROM   v_beds) AS NumberofBeds
    FROM   v_bedallocations bed, 
               v_dbpatientadmissions pt, 
               v_beds wardbed 
    WHERE  pt.admissionnumber = bed.admissionnumber 
               AND pt.admissionid = wardbed.admissionid 
               AND bed.bedname = wardbed.bedname 
    GROUP  BY bed.bedname, 
                  pt.regcode, 
                  pt.admissionnumber, 
                  pt.admissionid, 
                  pt.admitdate, 
                  pt.dischargedate, 
                  wardbed.bedid, 
                  bed.bedname, 
                  wardbed.ward 
)

SELECT *, 
100 * LOS_day/(NumberofBeds*Datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate)) as JustDoItInlineFormulaResult
FROM CTE
```

Comment: when manual calculating it doesn't return the same value as the formula used in the query  is there another approach ?

Comment: If `100 * LOS_day/(NumberofBeds*Datediff(day, @FromDate, @ToDate))` is the correct formula, then feeding that formula data in SQL should give you the same result as doing it on paper or in Excel.  I suspect that if doing the math in SQL is giving unexpected results, that the problem is actually in the query that's feeding data into the query (the group-bys, maybe)?  If you provide some sample data for each table in the query, we may be able to help more (then we can test it).  If you made a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/), that would help us help you even more.